# Accessing a MS Access database with Qt on Win7 X64

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ms-access

I used to have a Qt application which connected to a MS Access database (named `JSpo2014.accbd`) using the following code :

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
db.setDatabaseName("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};FIL={MS Access};DSN='';DBQ=C:\\2014\\bd\\JSpo2014.accdb");
db.open();
```

My Qt application is developed with Qt Creator, using Qt5.3.0 for MinGW x86.

It used to work fine on these configs :

- WinXP with Office 2010x86 installed
- Win7x86 with Office 2010x86 installed
- Win7x86 with Office 2013x86 installed

But it is **not** working on any of these configs :

- Win7x64 with Office 2010x86
- Win7x64 with Office 2013x86
- Win7x64 with Office 2013x64

I get he following error message :

`"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"`

`"QODBC3: Unable to connect"`

How can I make it work on Win7x64 with Office installed ?

Comment: Do you place the database driver dll in a folder named sqldrivers alongside the executable?

Comment: @Nejat : The problem I'm facing is even before any deployment, it's in the Qt Creator environnement.

Comment: i'm wondering if its a simple typo, You have \\bd\\ in your DBQ path, should this really be \\db\\ for "database" ?

Comment: @Lucretius : thanks for your comment. It's not a typo, it's a french abbreviation for 'base de données' (database in french) ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need a 64 bit driver as you shown everything works on your Windows running in a 32 bit environment, but when you try to run on a 64 bit environment you are unable to connect. Having 32 bit office is not going to solve this problem because windows is still running in a 64 bit environment. You would assume that it should be able to run anything 32 bit inside of a 64 bit environment, however that is not always the case and is never the case trying to run 64 bit inside a 32 bit environment. I would look into trying to get 64 versions if possible. That should negate your problem.